# Insert image from object to src

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to create `LI` and `IMG` from `UL` and insert image to `IMG` to display in a DOM.

Here is my code. Thank you very much.

```js
let data = {
  cats: {
    names: ['cat-1', 'cat-2'],
    photos: ['image/cat-1.jpg" alt="cat"', 'image/cat-2.jpg" alt="cat'],
    count: [0, 0]
  }
};

const createImageItem = () => {
  console.log(data.cats.photos.length);
  let UL = document.getElementById('list');
  let LI = document.createElement('li');
  let IMG = document.createElement('img');
  LI.appendChild(document.createTextNode('data.cats.photos[0])'));
  UL.appendChild(LI);
};
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Comment: You need to link `data.cats.photos[0]` as the attribute value of `src` for your `img` element.

Comment: setAttribute for image and link `data.cats.photos[0]`?

Comment: A standard html img tag has the image url in the `src` attribute like this: `<img src="/somelink.jpg" alt="cat" />` so you need to add a `src` attribute and add the image link to that attribute.

Comment: Your snippet never calls `createImageItem()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `index` to get data and use it like this -

```js
let data = {
  cats: {
    names: ['cat-1', 'cat-2'],
    photos: ['image/cat-1.jpg" alt="cat"', 'image/cat-2.jpg" alt="cat'],
    count: [0, 0]
  }
};

const createImageItem = (index) => {

  let UL = document.getElementById('list');
  let LI = document.createElement('li');
  let IMG = document.createElement('img');
  IMG.src = data.cats.photos[index];
  LI.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data.cats.names[index]));
  LI.appendChild(IMG);
  UL.appendChild(LI);
};

console.log(data.cats.photos.length);
createImageItem(0);
createImageItem(1);
```

```html
<ul id="list">
</ul>
```

Comment: The images are set on the DOM but it does not show on the DOM. What am I missing here? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @KrittiyaClark Check whether image urls are correct or not as they are relative urls, OR if you want to just test then try adding image urls like [this](https://irresistiblepets.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/img-cat.jpg)

Comment: I changed from `image/cat-1.jpg` to `/image/cat-1.jpg` but it still does not work.

Comment: @KrittiyaClark please check whether `image` directory is present or not in your site directory and also check for image file inside that directory with same name mentioned in javascript

Comment: I put `.` on the DOM like this `./image/cat-1.jpg` it shows the image but if I did it in an object it does not show the image.

Comment: It works with this `['image/cat-1.jpg', 'image/cat-2.jpg']`.

Comment: @KrittiyaClark it will work if that files are present in website host directory, happy to help :)